# Need a good relation extractor

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I'm doing a NLP project.

The purpose of the project is to extract possible relationship between two things. For example, for a pair "location" and "person" the extracted results would be "near", "lives in", "works in", etc.

Is there any existing NLP tool capable of doing this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a few different tools you might want to look at:

### MITIE

MIT's new **[MITIE](https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE)** tool supports basic relationship extraction. Included in the distribution are 21 English binary relation extraction models trained on a combination of Wikipedia and Freebase data. You can also train your own custom relation detectors. Here's a listing of the MITIE/MITIE-models/english/binary_relations/ directory, which is downloaded when you run the `make MITIE-models` target during the build process (the names should be relatively self-explanatory):

- rel_classifier_book.written_work.author.svm
- rel_classifier_film.film.directed_by.svm
- rel_classifier_influence.influence_node.influenced_by.svm
- rel_classifier_law.inventor.inventions.svm
- rel_classifier_location.location.contains.svm
- rel_classifier_location.location.nearby_airports.svm
- rel_classifier_location.location.partially_contains.svm
- rel_classifier_organization.organization.place_founded.svm
- rel_classifier_organization.organization_founder.organizations_founded.svm
- rel_classifier_organization.organization_scope.organizations_with_this_scope.svm
- rel_classifier_people.deceased_person.place_of_death.svm
- rel_classifier_people.ethnicity.geographic_distribution.svm
- rel_classifier_people.person.ethnicity.svm
- rel_classifier_people.person.nationality.svm
- rel_classifier_people.person.parents.svm
- rel_classifier_people.person.place_of_birth.svm
- rel_classifier_people.person.religion.svm
- rel_classifier_people.place_of_interment.interred_here.svm
- rel_classifier_time.event.includes_event.svm
- rel_classifier_time.event.locations.svm
- rel_classifier_time.event.people_involved.svm

### OpenIE

**[OpenIE](https://github.com/knowitall/openie)** from the Univ of Washington will extract relationships from text, representing the output as triples in the form of `(Arg1, Arg2, Relation)`. For example, given the input sentence:

> The U.S. president Barack Obama gave his speech on Tuesday to thousands of people.

OpenIE will extract these binary relations:

- (Barack Obama, is the president of, the U.S.)
- (Barack Obama, gave, his speech)
- (Barack Obama, gave his speech, on Tuesday)
- (Barack Obama, gave his speech, to thousands of people)

*Note: OpenIE uses [a non-standard open source license](https://github.com/knowitall/openie/blob/master/LICENSE) that expressly prohibits commercial use.*

### Stanford Relation Extractor

The **[Stanford Relation Extractor](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/relationExtractor.shtml)** extracts relations Live_In, Located_In, OrgBased_In, and Work_For. If you want to use a different set of relations, you can train your own relation extractor using the code (details provided on the webpage).

If you want basic dependencies, you can also use the Stanford Dependency Parser:

The **[Stanford Dependency Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml)** (part of the Stanford Parser) will extract grammatical relations between words in a sentence. For example, given this input:

> Bills on ports and immigration were submitted by Senator Brownback, Republican of Kansas

The Stanford Parser will extract these grammatical dependencies:

- nsubjpass(submitted, Bills)
- auxpass(submitted, were)
- agent(submitted, Brownback)
- nn(Brownback, Senator)
- appos(Brownback, Republican)
- prep_of(Republican, Kansas)
- prep_on(Bills, ports)
- conj_and(ports, immigration)
- prep_on(Bills, immigration)

### GATE

**[GATE](https://gate.ac.uk/)** from the Univ of Sheffield also includes a relation extraction capability, though I've never used it myself. This presentation provides an overview of how it works: https://gate.ac.uk/sale/talks/gate-course-may10/track-3/module-11-ml-adv/module-11-relations.pdf

Comment: It seems that OpenIE suits my need. It finds potential relation from its knowledge base. However it is still very limited. For example, if I input "person" and "location", it didn't give you common relations like "lives in" or "works in" but many strange answers. Also it is strictly for non commercial use

Comment: Until machines achieve self-awareness and exterminate the human race, you'll need to extend/adapt/re-train tools like these to fit your needs. Otherwise, you'll need to be content with their default performance & limitations out of the box.

Comment: I ran the OpenIE 4.1 binary but got the following error: The US president Barack Obama gave speech to thousands of people on Tuesday.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.googlecode.clearnlp.tokenization.EnglishTokenizer.protectEmoticon
s(EnglishTokenizer.java:335)
        at com.googlecode.clearnlp.tokenization.EnglishTokenizer.getTokenList(En
glishTokenizer.java:109)
        at com.googlecode.clearnlp.tokenization.AbstractTokenizer.getTokens(Abst
ractTokenizer.java:58)
        at edu.knowitall.tool.tokenize.ClearTokenizer.tokenize(ClearTokenizer.sc
ala:22)

Comment: Have you successfully run the OpenIE on your own device?

Comment: No, but only because of their silly non-standard license. If you have specific questions about how to operate their tool, I'd recommend posting questions to their GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: I like OpenIE's homepage that lets you search a triplet. This functionality is what I was exactly looking for. I hope they can release an API so other people can use it.

Comment: Shameless plug: Stanford CoreNLP now has an OpenIE system as well (standalone: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.shtml; or as a CoreNLP annotator: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/openie.html), and can be commercially licensed as a component of CoreNLP.

Answer (score 4):

The MIML-RE relation extractor (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/mimlre.shtml) could also be useful, if you're looking for one of the relations in the KBP relation set (see http://surdeanu.info/kbp2014/TAC_KBP_2014_Slot_Descriptions_V1.1.pdf). Admittedly, this is a much bigger system that's more of a pain to set up than the "relation" annotator in CoreNLP.

Probably the easiest way to get started with this option, is to download http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22stanford-kbp%22 (make sure to also download the models, as well as all of the dependencies). From there, there are a bunch of relatively low-barrier entry methods in `SlotfillingTasks` (e.g., `getSlotsInSentence()` gets all relations for a given entity, or `classifyRelation()` classifies the relation between two entities in a sentence).

Comment: Stanford's page has only NER download. I cannot find their IE tool

Comment: Yangrui, there's a big download link on this page for the Stanford Relation Extractor: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/relationExtractor.shtml

Comment: Thanks for providing the link!

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to take a look at [ReVerb](http://reverb.cs.washington.edu/). It performs Open Information Extraction, that is, you don't need to specify the type of relationships to extract. It automatically identifies and extracts all kinds of verb-mediated relationships between two nouns/nouns-phrases.

It's based on simple rules over part-of-speech tags therefore its extremely fast, that is, compared to other systems which rely on syntactic parsing.

The code is available [here](https://github.com/knowitall/reverb)

UPDATE:     I've written in a blog post, how to use ReVerb PoS-patterns to extract relational triples from news articles:

http://davidsbatista.net/blog/2017/05/08/ReVerb

Comment: ReVerb is the old version of OpenIE. The current version is 4.0